# php session behaving strangely

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-cookies

I have a login.php in the root directory. On valid user login, it executes the following code :

```
function log_in($id,$keep_login)
{
$_SESSION['auth'] = true;
$_SESSION['id'] = $id;
if($keep_login==TRUE) {
    setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+LOGGED_IN_TIME);
}
}
```

On login.php, in the starting, after including header file (header file contains session_start on first line), I check if a user is logged in using this function :

```
function logged_in()
{
if(!isset($_SESSION['auth'])||empty($_SESSION['auth'])||!isset($_SESSION['id'])||empty($_SESSION['id']))
{
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

And if the user is already logged in, I redirect them to profile.php using :

```
if(logged_in())
{
    header('Location: profile.php');
}
```

I have another file enter.php in /sources/enter.php

The login data from login.php is sent to enter.php . However, in enter.php , I see that the user is already logged in. i.e. logged_in() returns true. Curious about this, I echoed the session id on both login.php and enter.php , and the ids were different.

BTW, I include the header file like this : 
   $included=TRUE;
   require_once 'sources/headers.php';

Does the initialization of $included before session_start (session is started in headers.php) interfere with the session?

Although I AM logged_in, somehow my login.php cannot access my session. Can someone point the problem to me?

UPDATE : when I move enter.php to the root directory (same as login.php), it works like it should. Although for security reasons, I want to move it to /sources/enter.php . Any solution?

ANOTHER UPDATE : just came to know that when I move the enter.php to the root directory, 
the files in any subdirectory cannot access the session. The session variables are there, but the session id is different.

AND ONE MORE UPDATE : I just discovered, that the session id in the subdirectories is another id, and contains different $_SESSION variables. What I mean, that root directory has $_SESSION['id']=1 and the subdirectories have $_SESSION['id']=4. Maybe this is because the session id's are different.

Comment: different ids = different sessions. your session cookie settings are probably incorrect, leading to multiple sessinos, one for each directory on your site in which sessions are being used.

Comment: @MarcB that could be it, although I'm not sure. Because I cannot access the session in any of the file present in the root directory, but the session is accessible in all files in /sources/ folder. If this is the problem, how can I fix the incorrect session cookie settings? EDIT : when i moved enter.php to root directory, and called the log_in function, I can access the session in all files in my root directory but cannot access them in /sources/ . What you're saying might be true here/ I just need to know the settings for trying it.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php  look for `session.cookie_path`.

Comment: @MarcB I checked it out. It is already set to '/' . Doesn't that mean that the cookie should be accessible by all sub directories present in the root folder too?
I'm sure that I read somewhere, session_id is transferred through cookies. And when I checked, the files in sub directories had different session_id than the one in root directory. This may be a problem of cookies.

Comment: it is a cookie problem. try doing a `phpinfo()` in each of your subdirs where the sessions aren't working, and confirm the value of the session.cookie_path in each. just because it's right in ONE directory doesn't mean it's right in others. PHP config/ini values can be overriden/changed on a per-directory basis.

Comment: @MarcB I tried phpinfo in the sub directory. The cookie path is set to '/'.
Also, the session variables are still accessible in the sub directory, but the session id is still different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any output by the server before `session_start()` will interfere and cause your session to fail.

I'm not sure if that's your case but you should add `session_start()` as the first thing written in your config file. Make sure it's the first thing ever executed on a page.

Sometimes `session_start()` gets rekt if your file encoding is not `utf8-without-bom` (you should be using that at all times).

Comment: session_start() is the first thing in my headers.php file. Will it be better to explicitly start a session on every page? Because I include headers.php in every page, I thought it would be better to start the session in it. Also, why is it that it works when I moved the enter.php file to the same directory as login.php?

Comment: @abhishek If you do it in the headers page, then you dont have to do it again on the individual pages

Comment: @Krimson yes I already know that part. I was just wondering, which is the suggested way in this case : to call session_start() on every page's start, or to let it be in headers.php? Although I don't think it will make any difference.

Comment: @abhishek its better to do it in the header to stick to the DRYness approach (Don't Repeat Your self)

Comment: @Krimson yeah that's exactly what I thought.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem. It was not in the script. When I used another browser, it worked perfectly. Then i thought that Chrome must have preserved the old session cookie, and was still using it when in the subdirectory. I cleared cache, and it now works. Huh! Such a simple answer it was, I still need to learn. Thanks guys for helping me out!